# How to access generated output file in Docker

Tags: python-3.x, docker

I have dockerized my python application. This application connects with Oracle database, pull out 10 rows from a table and then generate excel. I was able to build my image successfully with all dependent libraries and it's also executing fine. Now, I am not sure how to get generated excel file (*batchtable.xlsx*) in docker.
I am new to docker and would need your suggestion. I have checked output without storing records into excel and it's coming fine on console, so there is no code issue.

***Dockerfile***

```
FROM python:3.7.4-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libaio1 wget unzip

WORKDIR /opt/oracle
COPY File.py /opt/oracle

RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && rm -f instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    cd /opt/oracle/instantclient* && rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *README *jar uidrvci genezi adrci && \
    echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf && ldconfig


RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip 
RUN python -m pip install cx_Oracle
RUN python -m pip install pandas
RUN python -m pip install openpyxl

CMD [ "python", "/opt/oracle/File.py" ]
```

***File.py***

```
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd

#creating database connection
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('dev-tr01.com', '1222', service_name='ast041.com')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'usr', password='3451', dsn=dsn_tns)
c = conn.cursor()

query ='SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE ROWNUM <10'
result = pd.read_sql(query, con=conn)
result.to_excel("batchtable.xlsx")

conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a `-v` switch to your `docker run` command. For instance:

   ```
   docker run -v <path>:/output YOUR_IMAGE_NAME
   ```

> Replace *path* with a valid path on your machine, for instance `c:\temp` on Windows.

2. Change your program to write to that directory:

   ```
   result.to_excel("/output/batchtable.xlsx")
   ```
3. If running Docker Desktop, in the Docker Desktop settings make sure your drive is shared.

Comment: I am still not able to see my output file : batchtable.xlsx . I am running Docker Desktop and my C drive is shared. I have updated my code to include /output : result.to_excel("/output/batchtable.xlsx"), build this image and run this command : docker run --rm -v c:/users/:/output python_driver:latest ls /output... It's showing all files in my c:/users directory and not the expected output excel..

Comment: If you run docker run --rm -v c:/users/:/output python_driver:latest ls /output, you create a container that executes the ls command but not your CMD command. That's not what you want. If you want to undertand what happens, use docker run --rm -it -v c:/users/:/output python_driver:latest sh (note the it switch), and you get an interactive command line. On the CL write "python /opt/oracle/File.py" then write "ls /output". What do you get ?

Comment: Also, it may be possible that docker doesn't have access rights to your c:\users folder.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion !! I am getting permission denied after executing python /opt/oracle/File.py. Error : PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/output/batchtable.xlsx'

Comment: Thanks for your tips !! I changed the directory and point it to some other location and executed above commands again and now I am able to see the excel on my host machine and inside /output folder. Then I re triggered docker run without sh command and it's generating file on my host machine as expected.. Thanks for working with me on this issue..

Answer (score 3):

You can access your data by mounting a volume into your container e.g.

```
docker run -ti -v $(pwd):/data IMAGE
```

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume

Comment: Could you please let me know what would be the value of $(pwd) ?

Comment: if you are on a unix/linux system `pwd` prints your current working directory - so `$(pwd)` will print your current directory. you can place an `echo` before the `docker` command to see what this would look like

Comment: FOR WINDOW: `pwd` = `cd` ===> `$(pwd)`  = `%cd%`